# Why isn't my image centering inside the div?

Tags: css

I've added a text-centre class to the div which the image appears within, but can't seem to get the image to centre? Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Thanks

It's the image to the right of the text under 'Peach Ambassador' that I'm trying to center on this page https://www.pepeandtete.com/about.html

Comment: `text-centre` works only for text, as the styling itself suggests in the wordt "text".
Try using `margin: 0 auto;` to center a container instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try `style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;"` in the `<img>`. If it works you can export the style to the css file.

Comment: Or just ```margin: 0 auto;```